How does the solution make sense for this ODE about distance and time?
I have an equation: $$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + 1 $$
where x and t represent distance and time respectively for $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ and $x = 0$ when $t = 0$
After solving this I arrived at the solution:
$$ x = \ln|\sec(t)|$$
but when I draw this as a distance time graph I get:

However I wonder how this makes sense. I understand that the graph would go exponentially up but I don't understand why it would ever go down. The ODE I described at the beginning could be interpreted as: the acceleration equals the velocity squared plus one. In that case you would never expect a negative velocity as the acceleration will always be positive (the squaring guarantees this).
But if the problem is the absolute value function then graphing it without it still generates further questions.
Graphing $ x = \ln(\sec{(t)})$ I get:

I'm still confused how this would make sense. Why would the particle after a while go back to the original position in the same manner as before and then shoot off again. Unless I'm wrong the original ODE doesn't suggest this at all.
Overall my question is: how do these graphs make sense?

The equation only makes physical sense for negative velocities. If the sign of the velocity is not fixed, linear motion with air friction and constant force would have the equation $\ddot x+|\dot x|\dot x=1$, so that the motions up and down are indeed not symmetric.

@ BadUsername: I am trying to look at a physics/math picture.  In my answer the second part definitely represents a uniform strength hanging cable. But can we get a physics dynamics phenomenon for which $ \ddot x= \dot x^2+1~$ holds good?

As a minor first nitpick: the function does not grow exponentially. It goes to infinity in finite time, that's much faster than exponential.
There are two points to cover here:
You are absolutely right that there is no significance to the other periods of $\ln(|\sec(x)|)$. The maximal domain of definition for this ODE given your initial condition is the single period $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. It turns out that the analytic formula we extract from the ODE extends to other values, but generally that shouldn't be interpreted to mean anything about the dynamics of the actual ODE. The ODE goes to infinity in finite time and that's the maximal domain of definition.
The second point is that this ODE is well posed both forward and backward in time (not uncommon for ODES). There is a unique solution on some time domain backwards in time (interpretation: if you saw a particle with given initial condition at $t= 0$ there is a unique possible path it could have take under this ODE prior to that time to put it in that position). And if the second derivative is positive at $t=0$ when $x' = 0$, then at negative times it must have had a negative velocity.

The most useful interpretation of the second derivative here is as it relates to the average value of $f$. A positive second derivative as you have, means that the average value of $f$ is larger than $f$ itself. This is true for you for any open interval contained in the period of your function. In summary, the positivity of the second derivative just means your first derivative (the slope) is increasing, but that slope could have been negative.

Starting from your initial condition at $t= 0$, the slope is indeed always positive. There is negative slope for $ t< 0$, but that's to be expected, and the rest of the negative slope is on other branches of the solution you can't get to from that initial condition.

Your interesting question touches on a physics situation (velocity, acceleration) and its mathematical representation; accordingly, we should examine the common area for the contradiction.
The multiple branching that appears here is an artifact of mathematical representation, not particle physics dynamics or an elastic structural continuum phenomenon underlying their ode formulations.
How and from what physics situation this equation of motion arises is not clear. For want of a better physics model assume for the time being a particle hypothetically moving under action of a relativistic force times tangent length upto x-axis being conserved. Modelling (dotted as time derivative) it as:
$$ \frac{m\ddot y}{(c^2+\dot y^2)^{3/2}} ~ y (1+\dot y^2/c^2)^\frac12$$
product remains constant. For unit speed $c$
$${c^2 y \ddot y} =(c^2+\dot y^2) $$
gives an integrated $ (y- t) $ U plot up to $\infty$ as in the Desmos plot.
In physics a new force cannot come from nowhere in the opposite direction to create multiple U paths!
Next in the following mechanics case $(x,y)$ is taken in place of $(t,x)$.
The function $y=\sec x$ has for its domain as well as range $(-\infty,+ \infty).$ Its log is not real for negative arguments in domain $(\pi/2,3 \pi/2) $ and co-domains, and so the log of absolute value is taken if it makes sense to a mathematical context being considered.
From the physics of a hanging cable of unform strength only a single U branch need be considered. By equilibrium of forces we can derive the ODE of a hanging cable of uniform strength of varying cross-section which is minimum where tangent is horizontal. Both the cross-section area of cable and slope go to $ \infty $ when nearing vertical asymptotes.
Uniform Strength Cable
The ODE and integrated result obtained are
$$  \frac{yy^{''}}{1+y^{'2}}=1, ~~y =L_B \log \sec \frac{x}{L_B}$$
where $L_B$ is break length or specific strength (strength/density) property of the chosen cable material. (Bruch Laenge German).
Materially there is only one U curve representing a hanging cable above the x-axis.
